# Error (stderr) Traceback (most recent call last) Could anyone tell me why I'm getting that?

Tags: python-2.7

```
#!/bin/python

import sys


n = int(raw_input().strip())
myStick = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
lilStick=0
count=-100
myStick=sorted(myStick)
       while count <= len(myStick):
       myStick = [x for x in myStick if x != lilStick]
       lilStick= min(myStick)
       myStick=sorted(myStick)
       print len(myStick)
```

Error (stderr)
Traceback (most recent call last): File "solution.py", line 13, in lilStick= min(myStick) ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
Could anyone tell me why im getting that ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `lilStick= min(myStick)` , you are using min function to get minimum value from empty list, which is not possible.

so you can loop before this to handle the code better.

```
import sys
n = int(input().strip())
myStick = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
lilStick=0
count=-100
myStick=sorted(myStick)
while True:
       myStick = [x for x in myStick if x != lilStick]
       print ("Min",myStick)
       if len(myStick) >0:
           lilStick= min(myStick)
           myStick=sorted(myStick)
           print (len(myStick))
       else:
           break
```

Read more about Operators and python loops.

**Note:** Changed raw_input to input, parentheses for print statement because I checked the code in `version 3.5.1`. Hope you can do that changes to `version 2.7`.

Comment: @Geraldo Braho Was it helpful?

Comment: @ Siva Shanmugam I tried it but it didn't work , it's ok i didn't pay to much attention to it. I submitted the same code and passed all the cases.
Thank you very much for your help :)